# How to get Heroku web app to point to an AWS subdomain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, heroku, amazon-route53

I have just made a web app launched in Heroku, and I would like it to point to a www. ([www.example.com](http://www.example.com))subdomain, and get the root domain to redirect to the [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) subdomain.  Here's what I have so far:

In my S3 buckets, I have made an "example.com", and an "www.example.com" buckets.

1. The example.com bucket has all the code for the static website, and in "properties", I have "hosting type" as "redirect request", and the endpoint as a static website hosted in AWS.  When I go to "edit", I have the host name as the subdomain, and enabled redirect.  Below are the screenshots.

[image]

[image]

2. In the "www.example.com" bucket, in properties, I have redirect enabled as well, and the host name as the root domain.

[image]

[image]

3. In my Route 53 hosted Zone, I have the both the root domain, example.com, and [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) as records.  Both of them are record type A.  The root domain has the value of the S3 bucket link:

[image]

The subdomain record in Hosted Zone has a value of the cloudfront link that takes me to the static website:
[image]

I have also added both the root domain and subdomain to Heroku, and the platform gave me two DNS targets for me to input in AWS.  Given that I already have two S3 buckets, and two hosted zones for my root domain and subdomain, how would I point the DNS target to the subdomain, and have the root domain to automatically redirect to the subdomain? Do I need to add the DNS target to the root domain as well?